# Post data to webview in android

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to pass value in webview using post method?

```
engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);

engine.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
});

engine.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
engine.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
engine.loadUrl(url+"?ref=api&uname="+id+"&pass="+pass);
```

This is the way I am sending the data using get method, I want to use Post method.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
String postData = "username=my_username&password=my_password";
webview.postUrl(url,EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));
```

Comment: What is "BASE64" charset ??? According to https://github.com/android/platform_external_apache-http/blob/master/src/org/apache/http/util/EncodingUtils.java this will throw exception internally and will fallback to default charset (UTF-8 - as stated here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html "The platform's default charset is UTF-8")

Comment: if you not see EncodingUtils, add "android { useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' }" to your gradle

Comment: This is outdated - is there a way to do it without adding a legacy library? I don't presume the android developers don't need this functionality in API 25.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`postUrl`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#postUrl(java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D)) to use POST in `WebView`.

Answer (score 0):

Better with Base64.encode:

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
String postData = "username=my_username&password=my_password";
webview.postUrl(url,Base64.encode(postData.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
```

In some cases works better:

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
postData = "username="+URLEncoder.encode("my_username", "UTF-8")+"&password="+URLEncoder.encode("my_password", "UTF-8");
 webview.postUrl(url,postData.getBytes());
```