# Sending and receiving data from an activity to a webserver using webview in android

Tags: android, android-webview, payment-gateway

I am new to android development. I am developing an e-commerce app in which I want to use website server for payment. I think we can use **WebView** for that. I want to know how can we pass data from the app to the website server using **WebView** and complete the payment process through payment gateway of the website. Can someone please guide me with the code how to do so? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to modify your webpage to accept **POST** parameters and then loading the URL in **WebView** along with the parameters that you want to send to the webpage.

For finding out how to send post params, Please refer to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13191602/2534007