# How to make Post request from Android WebView Client?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, url-encoding

I need to make `x-www-form-urlencoded` post request from `Android` webView client. I am using `EncodingUtils` for encoding. Here is my code:

```
String postdata = "sUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fpayment%2Fpayu%2Fresponse&......."
.......
.......
 webView.postUrl("https://test.payu.in/_payment", EncodingUtils.getBytes(POSTDATA, "BASE64"));
```

I am using `BASE64` but what supposed to be there for `x-www-form-urlencided`? I tried to search but nothing is there. What is the right approach to do it?

Comment: String postdata contains an url with parameters so is more a GET request. postdata should not contain an url. And what is `POSTDATA` ? And why would you base64 encode data for a post? That parameter expects a char set like for instance "UTF-8".

Comment: This is the way to send the post data from Android webview. check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191384/post-data-to-webview-in-android

Comment: If you know the way then why ask here? And why should we check? Better react to the things i said and asked.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, use a html form and put it inside viewview 
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/index.html", , "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

Comment: Use a html form? I don't have that one and it's in android

Comment: Create a simple form then keep the base url as "https://test.payu.in/_payment" , and keep in asset folder. and load it in webview. On submit of form you can send post reqest